# Посчитать колличество символов с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
$(".ask-form textarea").on("keydown", function () {
    var text = $(".ask-form textarea").val();
    var counter = $("#ask-form-symbolCount");
    counter.text(300 - text.length);
})
```

Тоесть при нажатии на любую клавишу в `.ask-form textarea` считывается колличество символов
Мне нужно подсчитать колличество символов в `$(".ask-form textarea")` и записать её в `$("#ask-form-symbolCount")` (лимит 300 символов) пвпрочем как и показано в коде, но этот код работает некорректно (да и при нажатии на любую клавишу срабатывает). Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать или если есть собственные варианты кода то напишите. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Выглядит как рабочий код, только заменить keydown, на keyup (или и то и то)

Comment: или на `input` .

Comment: да, `input` лучше, но только если поддерживать ie8 не планируется или же `input propertychange`

Comment: Почему Вы пишете "срабатывает при нажатии на любую клавишу"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему Вы пишете, "срабатывают любые клавиши"? Срабатывают только символы и пробел, функциональные клавиши и управление не отражают событие.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ask-form textarea").val('');
    $(".ask-form textarea").on("keyup", function() {
        var text = $(".ask-form textarea").val();
        var counter = $("#ask-form-symbolCount");
        counter.text(30 - text.length);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form action="" class="ask-form">
   <textarea autofocus="" cols="30" id="" maxlength="30" name="" rows="5">        </textarea>
</form>
<p id="ask-form-symbolCount">30
</p>
```

Я установил максимальное кол-во символов равное 30 для удобства проверки. Срабатывает также enter, если надо исключить, надо будет поправить функцию.